# Problems with $_GET variable and strpos

Tags: php, get, strpos

I am trying to find a instance of a string inside another using strpos() but I am having problems.

```
      if(strpos($line, $_GET['search']) !== FALSE){ //does not work
```

$line is a single line of a text file read in by fgets() and $_GET['search'] is text passed in via the url.  This code never gets a match.  However same line with $_GET['search'] replaced with straight text works fine.

```
      if(strpos($line, "test") !== FALSE){ //got a match, works
```

I have tried casting the $_GET variable with strval, and nothing seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: There's probably something in `$_GET['search']` that you're not expecting, like extra whitespace. Maybe use `trim()` to clean it up. Use `var_dump($_GET['search']);` to see what's exactly in it.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize that I was getting the $_GET string wrapped in quotes.  That would account for it.  Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the code that's generating the URL, it's adding unnecessary quotes.

Comment: first you should test your value from get using var_dump